# Yii2 compare validation not working

Tags: javascript, php, yii2

My problem is compare validation is not working correctly. If my `min_bid_amount = 100` and `min_buy_amount=1000`, it's working. But problem occurs when `min_bid_amount = 500` and `min_buy_amount=1000`. It also gives me error message.

Here is my model rule

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['min_bid_amount','min_buy_amount'], 'number'],
        ['min_buy_amount', 'compare','compareAttribute'=>'min_bid_amount','operator'=>'>',
        'message'=>'Buying amount should be bigger than bid amount'],
        [['auction_start_date', 'auction_end_date', 'created'], 'safe'],
        [['id_product','min_bid_amount','min_buy_amount'], 'required']
    ];
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated. I think JS does not convert it into int type value. So how could I do that?

Comment: Please, provide the error message

Comment: "Buying amount should be bigger than bid amount" this is the error as per validation rule

Comment: when min_bid_amount = 500 and min_buy_amount=1000. This also display error message 'Buying amount should be bigger than bid amount' ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should change the [type](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-validators-comparevalidator.html#$type-detail) of validation to `number`:

```
    ['min_buy_amount', 'compare','compareAttribute'=>'min_bid_amount','operator'=>'>',
    'message'=>'Buying amount should be bigger than bid amount', 'type' => 'number'],
```